# grabbing specific columns of a csv

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

Can you please help to fix this script?

```
$ private=False
$ min_num_followers=100
$ max_num_followers=1000
$ awk -v private="$private" '$11=private' ExportData_followers_memoryweaver_37677682_10.csv  |  awk -v min_num_followers="$min_num_followers" '$9 > min_num_followers'| awk -v max_num_followers="$max_num_followers" '$9 < max_num_followers'  |awk -F"," '{x+=$8} END {print x}'
```

I want to get the rows in which the 9th column is > min_num_followers and < max_num_followers and also 11th column is private.
[image]

**I am not biased towards using awk anyways

Comment: Please copy-paste actual content, not screenshot. Also add your desired output.

Comment: @heemayl can't do so, the content is private!

Comment: Then post those as masked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `awk -F, '$9 > 500 && $9 < 1000 && $11 == "True"'` should work

Comment: Thanks, this worked awk -F, '$9 > 500 && $9 < 1000 && $11 = "False"'  ExportData_followers_sabaasafari_398725412_10.csv | wc -l

Comment: by the way seems it is not applying it on the correct columns. Does 9 pertain to I in CVS?

Comment: @MonaJalal here it is using comma as separator. If you want to use the pipe as a separator instead, then change `-F,` to `-F|`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need multiple `awk` commands - you can chain the logical conditions with `&&` (or `||` if the logic demands it).

Also you need to replace `$11=private` (assignment) by `$11==private` (logical test). So something like this should work:

```
awk -F"," -v private="$private" -v min_num_followers="$min_num_followers" -v max_num_followers="$max_num_followers" '
  $11==private && $9 > min_num_followers && $9 < max_num_followers
' ExportData_followers_memoryweaver_37677682_10.csv
```

If you want the output to be comma-separated, set `OFS = ","` either in the body of the `awk` expression or on the command line e.g.

```
awk -F"," -v private="$private" -v min_num_followers="$min_num_followers" -v max_num_followers="$max_num_followers" '
  $11==private && $9 > min_num_followers && $9 < max_num_followers
' OFS="," ExportData_followers_memoryweaver_37677682_10.csv
```

Comment: so in the output, commas are dropped, how can I maintain them in the awk -F"," '$9 > 100 && $9 < 1000 && $11 = "False"' ?

Comment: @MonaJalal the output field separator is called `OFS` so if you want comma-separated output you must set `OFS=","` either inside the expression or on the command line. As I mentioned above, you should use `$11 == "False"` not `$11 = "False"` if you want to make it *conditional on the value of* `$11`.

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming that these two both worked:

```
$ awk -F"," '$9 > 100 && $9 < 1000 && $11 == "False"' ExportData_followers_reddit_1702003595_10.csv | wc -l
1089
$ gawk -F"," '$9 > 100 && $9 < 1000 && $11 == "False"' ExportData_followers_reddit_1702003595_10.csv | wc -l
1089
```